# SAP Crystal Reports RESTful web services features doubts

Tags: c#, rest, crystal-reports

Last week I installed Crystal Server 2016 Trial version on a new server.  I had been able to move my Crystal Report 9 version reports successfully to the new version.  The only issue has been the misunderstanding of the APIs that Crystal Servers provides and the lack of information on them.

As per my understanding there are three choices right now:

- 1. Java SDK
- 2. C# SDK (http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/)
- 3. Web Service Rest SDK

The C# SDK:

- 1. Does not offer a NuGet package
- 2. There is a separate installation of the tools
     (http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/)
- 3. Once I added all the Crystal references to the project , I still was unable to figure out how to instantiate the SessionMgr and the Enterprise classes to query the InfoStore like in previous versions.

Because of that I went through the Rest API road.

https://help.sap.com/doc/businessobject_product_guides_boexir4_en_xi4sp6_cr_restful_ws_en_pdf/XI4.0.6/en-US/xi4sp6_cr_restful_ws_en.pdf

I was able to get back a X-SAP-LogonToken using the /biprws/logon/long URL.
But, I’m currently stuck trying to query ISTORE to do something similar to:

```
strQuery = "SELECT SI_ID FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE SI_PROGID = 
'CrystalEnterprise.Report' AND SI_NAME = '" & sReportName & "'"
Set objResults = IStore.Query(strQuery)
```

Does the Restful Web Services provides a URL that would let me query the ISTORE to get back the ID of a report based on the name of the report?

Answer (score -1):

I think if you post your query to the SAP Community you will get good help and pointers there: https://answers.sap.com/questions/ask.html